# How can I figure out why django-allauth isn't sending a confirmation e-mail?

Tags: django, django-allauth, amazon-ses

I am using Django-allauth and sending e-mail through Amazon SES. I want all accounts to verify their e-mails before they can log in, but the e-mail verification sending seems to fail silently. I've looked at the source code, where I saw I should set DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, but it still doesn't work.

Here's my config, in case I forgot anything obvious. I have django-smtp-ssl installed as email backend. Your help would be much appreciated!

```
# E-mail

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_smtp_ssl.SSLEmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ['EMAIL_USER']
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ['EMAIL_PASSWORD']
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'Verified-email <verified-ses-email@example.com>'

# Auth

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'
SOCIALACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = True
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'username_email'
```

Comment: Change ```EMAIL_BACKEND``` to ```'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'```, so you will see if email is send or not. If it is send then it is blocked by SES.

Comment: There is more to sending emails than just getting it off the SMTP server. I wrote about some things to keep in mind (DKIM, SPF, bounce processing, PTR etc) https://github.com/fmalina/emails. I am using this code with allauth on FlatmateRooms and now making it generic and configurable to open-source it all.

Comment: I tried with the other adapter, but no luck. I will try to set some breakpoints in the django-allauth code and see what is happening. SES also mentions 0 emails have been sent, so I think the error is on my side.

I will keep you updated, thanks for the input!

Comment: I think I found where it comes from. The confirmation e-mail doesn't seem to be sent simply when submitting an allauth SignupForm. There is something else to add, I will look in the views and add that to my views. Seems counter-intuitive, but at least I found why it happens.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found what I was missing.

In my signup view, I added one more line:

```
from allauth.account.utils import complete_signup
from allauth.account import app_settings
# some other code
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(request)
            # Added this!
            complete_signup(request, user,app_settings.EMAIL_VERIFICATION, "/")
            # etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

`DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL` should be a valid address on `EMAIL_HOST`.

And you also can verify it as below.

```
$ python manage.py shell
Python 2.7.9 (default, Jun 29 2016, 13:08:31)
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> settings.EMAIL_BACKEND
'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
>>> from django.core.mail import send_mail
>>> send_mail('test message', 'this is a test message', settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, ['recipient@example.com'])
1
>>>
```